# Wired computer cannot ping each other on same network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ping

I have a weird case where device on wired connection cannot ping each other. It gave me `Destination host unreachable`.

192.168.1.1 - router
192.168.1.2 - laptop (wired)
192.168.1.3 - Smartphone (wireless)
192.168.1.4 - Raspberry Pi (wired)

Every device can ping the router.
laptop can ping everyone except Raspberry Pi.
Smartphone can ping everyone.
Pi can ping everyone except laptop.

If I use wireless connection on the laptop, it can ping the Pi but not wired, so `wired to wired` cannot ping each other, but `wired - wireless` and `wireless - wireless` can. Here's my settings :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks